# How to remove validation from address fields in Magento 1.9 on Registration Page.

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento and I want to make Street and City fields optional on magento registration page. Can anyone please guide or give any idea that how to do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

comment out the line in the specific phtml files inside the tags that looks like below code

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('name-of-form');
```

Otherwise, comment out the line in **page.xml** with:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
```

Comment: I just need to remove validation from street address and city fields on registration page.